# Recursive function in Coq

Tags: coq

```
Inductive my_type := 
| Type_pol : Z -> my_type
| Type_matrix : Z -> my_type.

Inductive redPair := 
| RedPair_interpretation : my_type -> redPair.

Inductive orderingProof := 
| OrderingProof_redPair : redPair -> orderingProof.

Inductive trsTerminationProof := 
| TrsTerminationProof_ruleRemoval : 
   orderingProof -> trsTerminationProof -> trsTerminationProof.
```

I want to write a function that

```
Definition return_mytype (t : my_type) : option nat :=
  match t with
   | Type_pol _ => None
   | Type_matrix i => Some (Z.to_nat i)
  end.
Definition return_redPair (r : redPair ) : option nat :=
  match r with
   | RedPair_interpretation mty => return_mytype mty
 end. 
Definition return_orderProof (d : orderingProof) : option nat :=
  match d with
  | OrderingProof_redPair r => return_redPair r
  end.

Definition return_trsTermProof (t : trsTerminationProof) : option nat :=
   match t with
    | TrsTerminationProof_ruleRemoval d _t => return_orderProof d
   end.
```

I want to write the function `return_trsTermProof` that also work in the case not only take an argument `d` but also if there is an `t:trsTerminationProof` for example

```
Fixpoint return_trsTermProof (t : trsTerminationProof) : option nat :=
   match t with
    | TrsTerminationProof_ruleRemoval d t => 
     (* I don't know how can I take the function (return_orderProof d) *) ...
     return_trsTermProof t 
   end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to return `return_trsTermProof t_` if `return_orderProof d` returns `none`?

```
Fixpoint return_trsTermProof (t : trsTerminationProof) : option nat :=
  match t with
  | TrsTerminationProof_ruleRemoval d t_ =>
    match return_orderProof d with
    | None   => return_trsTermProof t_
    | Some n => Some n
    end
  end.
```

If your inductive sets didn't have any more constructors, you could also define it like this:

```
Fixpoint return_trsTermProof (t : trsTerminationProof) : option nat :=
  match t with
  | TrsTerminationProof_ruleRemoval (OrderingProof_redPair (RedPair_interpretation (Type_pol    z))) t_ => return_trsTermProof t_
  | TrsTerminationProof_ruleRemoval (OrderingProof_redPair (RedPair_interpretation (Type_matrix z))) t_ => Some (Z.to_nat z)
  end.
```

Comment: I have a case that when there are 'Some n' return 'Some n' and then continue with the argument 't: trsTerminationProof'.How can I parse this case?